# How to solve StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in my case?

Tags: java, android

```
public static float getSelectedHeight() { 
  String selectedHeightValue = (String)heightSpin.getSelectedItem(); 
  if (heightSpin.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0 ) { 
    String feets = selectedHeightValue.substring(0,1); 
    String inches = selectedHeightValue.substring(2,4); 

    return (float) (Float.parseFloat(feets) * 0.3048) + (float) (Float.parseFloat(inches) * 0.0254); 

  } else { 
    return Float.parseFloat(selectedHeightValue); 
  } 
}
```

Error    String index out of bound exception i don't know how to solve it.. Please Help me in solving this issue

```
**java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; regionStart=2; regionLength=2**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be the lines with `selectedHeightValue.substring(...)`

To solve it, first of all as a general rumb of thumb, before doing any operation with substring, you should check selectedHeightValue must be valid (so not NULL and not EMPTY).

And then make sure your `string size` is enough to make a substring of it (so that it does not exceed its size when you try to access a position in the string that doesn't exist).

`Exmple`: the string "ABC" has size 3. And have positions: 0,1,2. If you try to access the string "ABC" in position 3 and up (4,5,6...) than I guess is gonna throw an error because you want to access something that doesn't exist.

Comment: You do know that your 'rule of thumb' is wrong in Java right? String comparisons must be done with `equals`

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE Thanks I was in rush when writing. I updated the answer. :)